# Wann wird "Telegrammstil" heute noch benutzt?

Tags: grammar, style, abbreviation

*["Telegrammstil"](http://www.dwds.de/?kompakt=1&qu=Telegrammstil)* ist eine aus Platzgründen eingeführte grammatikalische Verknappung in [Telegrammen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegramm).

Heute gibt es aber keine Telegramme mehr; dennoch ist der Telegrammstil weit verbreitet.

> *"Bin kurz weg"*

Gibt es Regeln, nach denen diese verkürzte Schreibweise verfasst wird? Wo darf man im Telegrammstil schreiben und wo nicht?

Comment: Jetzt nur im Sinne auf [Pro-Drop-Verkürzung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-Drop-Sprache) oder auch mit weiteren Abkürzungen, Auslassungen, etc?

Comment: Nur bedingt passend auf Telegramme, aber hier eine Arbeit, die sehr viele schöne verknappende Beispiele enthält: http://www.linguistik.hu-berlin.de/syntax/docs/fries1988_SP3.pdf

Comment: *Ankomme Freitag, den 13., um vierzehn Uhr, Christine* http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGoq5QF8wQg

Comment: Was heißt 'eingeführt'? Das wurde einfach von sparsamen Naturen praktiziert, und ist mit Pinwand, Klebenotizen und SMS schlimmer geworden, ned war? Außer im Schulunterricht und bei Amtshandlungen ist man sprachlich ohnehin zu nichts verpflichtet - als weiterer Ort des Untergangs der Kultur fällt mir jedoch die Zeitungsüberschrit ein: "Griechenlandrettung vertagt".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In der Nachrichtenberichterstattung taucht der Begriff mitunter auf:

> Alle Infos im Telegramm-Stil
>
> ++++++++ 16:26 Uhr
>   BRITISCHE POLIZEI – MINDESTENS 33 BESTÄTIGTE TOTE BEI ANSCHLÄGEN IN LONDON
>
> ++++++++ 15:39 Uhr
>   ...

Etwas Ähnliches wie der Telegrammstil ist die Kürzelsprache, die viele Jugendliche in SMS-Nachrichten verwenden. Einige Beispiele:

- 8ung (Achtung)
- GUK (Gruß und Kuss)
- sz (schreib zurück)
- bb (bis bald)

AKLA?

---

*Telegrammstil* ist übrigens auch eine [Bezeichnung für eine bestimmte Sprechstörung](http://wissen.de/wde/generator/wissen/ressorts/gesundheit/medizin/index,page=4281378.html):

> Eine Bezeichnung für eine Störung des Sprechens, die nach einer bereits abgeschlossenen Sprachentwicklung auftritt, z. B. durch eine Schädigung der Sprachregion im Gehirn oder im Rahmen einer Schizophrenie. Der Telegrammstil äußert sich in der Bildung von einfachen, fehlerhaften Satzstrukturen, wie z. B. »Essen haben«.

Comment: ... taucht das *Phänomen* auf, nicht der *Begriff*, bzw. letzterer nur zufällig `"GL&U: Splattne kritisiert Telegramstil"`