# Literatur zum Thema Musiktext-Analyse

Tags: literature, lyrics

Für eine Forschungsarbeit suche ich aktuell Literatur, die sich mit der systematischen Analyse von Songtexten beschäftigt, vor allem von deutschen Songtexten. Ich möchte untersuchen, ob sich Songtexte im Verlauf der Zeit (zwischen 1950 und heute) vereinheitlicht haben. 
Dabei geht es mir um Text-Eigenschaften wie: Thema, Wortschatzumfang, Informationsgehalt, u.s.w..

Ich gehe mal davon aus, dass sich schon schlaue Köpfe mit dem Thema beschäftigt haben. Dazu habe ich auch schon recherchiert unter diversen Begriffen, finde i. d. R. aber nur Analysen, die bspw. Tonarten oder Harmonien eines Songs analysieren.

Hier ein paar Beispiele auf was ich grob abziele:

- [Instrumentational Complexity of Music Genres and Why Simplicity Sells](http://Instrumentational%20Complexity%20of%20Music%20Genres%20and%20Why%20Simplicity%20Sells)
- [What Makes Popular Culture Popular? Product Features and Optimal Differentiation in Music](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0003122417728662)

*Zur Info: Ich bin Wirtschaftsinformatiker, daher ist das nicht meine Kern-Domäne. Ich bin aber durchaus in der Lage alle Paper zu lesen ;) oder ggf. das Thema technisch zu betrachten.*

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht genau, was Du meinst, wenn Du von Vereinheitlichung schreibst. Wahl der Worte, Wahl der Themen? Rhythmische Strukturen? Wenn es spezifisch um deutsche Liedtexte geht, kann ich noch eine gewisse Relevanz auf dieser Seite erkennen ("on-topic"), wobei das vielleicht auch eher was für das Musiker-Stackexchange wäre.

Comment: Das ist korrekt, es geht um Text-Eigenschaften wie: Thema, Wortschatzumfang, Informationsgehalt. In der Arbeit geht es nur um deutsche Texte, aber ich kann mich natürlich auch auf Analysen in anderen Sprachen beziehen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about expertise in German Music - not German as langauge.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm I would say, the analysis of lyrics is more related to the language than to music. Imagine the same question asking for analysis of poems instead of songtexts...

Comment: @Arsak: D.h., weil es so sehr auf die Sprachentwicklung ankommt, wie z.B. hier (https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3750/36160) oder hier (https://german.stackexchange.com/q/7624/36160) oder hier (https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2220/36160)? Statt des Tags "history" bei music.SE (https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)?

Comment: (or https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Genau.

Comment: @FabianTe: Das ist nicht speziell auf Textinhalt, sondern nur auf "Erkennbarkeit" gemünzt. Daher unklar, inwiefern es überhaupt einen Anhaltspunkt bietet: https://www.heise.de/tp/features/Wiegen-Heil-und-Tanzlieder-sind-universell-erkennbar-Liebeslieder-nicht-4594885.html

Comment: Was meinst Du mit "im Verlauf der Zeit"? Seit dem Mittelhochdeutschen?

Comment: Ich betrachte Titel zwischen 1950 und heute. Literatur muss nicht zwingend auf den Zeitraum beschränkt sein, wird es aber wohl kaum mit dem Focus geben, den ich habe.

Comment: Also zumindest was den Wortschatzumfang im deutschen Rap angeht, gibt es eine Gegenüberstellung: https://story.br.de/rapwortschatz/#/chapter/1/page/2
Hier kannst du ja einfach schauen, seit wann der jeweilige Künstler 'im Game' ist, ich denke bis zum Anfang der 2000er kann das für dieses Genre hilfreich sein.

Comment: Ich empfehle, in den Forschungsdatenbanken der Universitäten dafür zu suchen. Sorry, für diese Q&A-Seite ist das viel zu speziell.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's way too difficult and out of scope for what a non-exploratory Q&A site can solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich bin weder Musikus noch Fachperson. Aber das Thema kommt bei mir aus einer anderen Ecke recht bekannt vor: Text-Analyse von Internet-Texten.

Vielleicht helfen die Stichwort "sentiment analyse" und "text mining" weiter.

Insbesondere in der praktischen Umsetzung, durch werkzeuge (nur Beispiele), wie

- https://www.txtwerk.de/de/ (unbedingt ausprobieren) oder
- inCode (http://insius.com/de/produkte/incore/) oder
- IBM Watson.

Sonst noch diese Paper gefunden:

- https://ids-pub.bsz-bw.de/frontdoor/index/index/docId/996
- https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-476-03455-7
- https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/zrs/8/1-2/article-p124.xml?language=de
- http://webdoc.sub.gwdg.de/ebook/serien/hr/escripta/1_2011.pdf

Comment: Hi Walter, danke für die Antwort!
Edit: Die Arbeit ist mittlerweile abgeschlossen. Letzten Endes wurden tatsächlich ähnliche Werkzeuge verwendet, weshalb ich eine Antwort mal als akzeptiert markiere. Ich persönlich schätze, dass das Thema ansich zu komplex war und eigentlich eine Vor-Analyse hätte stattfinden müssen, welche Features sich aus für einen Song extrahieren lassen.